# Does fmt library handle printing std::chrono::time_point?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono, fmt

The [documentation](https://fmt.dev/dev/syntax.html#chrono-specs) for the C++ fmt libary says, about the "chrono format specifiers":

> Specifiers that have a calendaric component such as 'd' (the day of month) are valid only for std::tm and not durations or *time points*.

But, I can create `std::chrono::time_point` and print it using %d and other letters.

```
using std::chrono::system_clock;
using std::chrono::time_point;

time_point<system_clock> t = system_clock::now();
fmt::print("{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}", t);
// Prints: 2022-09-08 21:27:08
```

Maybe I'm not understanding the docs; I'm not 100% sure about the meaning of some of the terms, like "calendaric component".

I just want to print a time point in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (`YYYY-mm-ddTHH:MM:SSZ`) and for some reason this does not seem to be available in the standard library along with the `chrono` types.

Is printing a `time_point` (like I did above) supported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part of the documentation is a bit outdated. With recent versions of {fmt} you can use `d` and similar format specifiers with `time_point`, e.g.

```cpp
#include <fmt/chrono.h>

int main() {
  using std::chrono::system_clock;
  using std::chrono::time_point;
  time_point<system_clock> t = system_clock::now();
  fmt::print("{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}", t);
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Ejsz96Yq5)

Comment: This seems to work only for a `time_point<system_clock>`. For a `time_point<file_clock> tpfc`, you can do `file_clock::to_sys(tpfc)`.